# Copy from One Table to Another (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from one table to another table in excel. Currently, the code that I have doesn't do anything.

```
Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets(3).ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange("A" & LastRow1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Comment: What does not working mean? Does something happen that shouldn't? Does nothing happen at all? Excel crashes? Is there a specific line that errors out?

Comment: If the code worked at some point then I would check that your sheet indexes have not changed (is the correct sheet being referenced?) or if your table names have changed (name manager)

Comment: @urdearboy I didn't change the references and the name manager is the same as well. The code doesn't do anything. It was working before I saved and close yesterday, then I opened it today and didn't work.

Comment: You are using sheet indexes so if you moved the sheets around that constitutes a change. But if that were the case, you would prob be able to find data pasted on the wrong sheet

Comment: @urdearboy even changing them to the name references, it still doesn't work.

Comment: `Worksheets(3).ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange("A" & LastRow1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` is not valid syntax.  Probaly you meant `Worksheets(3).ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Range("A" & LastRow1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`  That said, it may still not work (sometimes) depending on what rows are visible in your tables.

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks! I knew I was missing something small I for some reason I couldn't tell what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why SpecialCellType is used? do you want to copy the filtered range? Again, pasting in visible range is not supported, So you must provide a single destination cell or range of same number of cells for pasting. 
However, following is the working code for your reference:

```
LastRow1 = Worksheets(3).ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets(3).ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Offset(LastRow1)
```

Comment: So the data is filtered in one table. I am trying to paste the filtered data to the end of another table. Sorry if I'm not being super descriptive.

Comment: I tried your solution, it worked for me with some adjustment. Thanks!